# References of arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
    public class sss {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
    change(array);

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        System.out.println(array[i]);

  }

  public static void change(int [] array)
  {
      int[] temp = new int[4];
      for (int i =0; i<temp.length;i++)
          temp[i] = i;
      array =  temp;
  }

}
```

Im trying to change my array,
Why is the output is 1,2,3 and not 0,1,2,3 ?
Thanks.

Comment: becase array parameter is pass by value not pass by reference

Comment: Thanks for the answer,
but what do you mean ?

Comment: The `array` reference in the method is just a copy of the `array` reference outside the method. Therefore changing it to a new value inside the method doesn't affect anything outside the method.

Comment: If its just a coppy, Why, for example when I write array[0] = 1 in the method, it changes the terms outside the method ?

Comment: Because both `array`s point to the same array, you can use either one to change the elements of it. Changing the `array` reference itself however does nothing.

Comment: So.. There is any option to create a new array in some method outside the main , and change the reference of the original array to the new one ?